# Transparent layout - not transparent on Android 2.3

Tags: android, layout

I have a transparent layout used for holding a banner advert in my app. The layout sits on top of my game area constantly, but the ads only appear once in a while. The code works as follows:

```
transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);   
game_frame_layout.addView(transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner);
setContentView(game_frame_layout);
```

When I want an ad to be shown I do a

```
transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner.addView(adView);
```

When I want the ad to disappear I do a

```
transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner.removeView(adView);
```

This works perfectly on my Galaxy S !! with 4.0.3, but on my Galaxy tab with 2.3 I find that my transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner turns black as soon as the add appears, and remains black forever more, even when the ad is removed.

Any idea what is happening?... and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** after some experimentation, I worked out that the colour of the layout is not changing, but the alpha channel is. My guess is that perhaps the SDK of the banner ad system is calling some function(s) to make sure that the banner itself is not transparent, and then (depending on the OS version) this is having the side effect of making its parent layout non-transparent.

Comment: Have you tryed using an xml layout and position the ad on the desired location? So you just make it visible/invisible when showing and hiding.

Comment: how you solve it then？I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the layout non transparent before adding the ad banner.

When you want to remove the ad, remove the ad banner view and make the layout transparent again.

Can you try adding this line again after you remove the ad.

```
transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Surprisingly it didn't work. The transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner remains black.

Comment: Can you post the entire layout file? Probably there's some problem there?

Comment: If you mean the xml file - well there isn't one. Its all created programatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using admob, try latest 6.0 library, it has several improvements (as I can see) in control over the look of ad, it seems to pay more attention to the attributes described in [Best Practices: Specifying ad colors](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/bestpractices#adcolors). I had similar problem with previous release of the library. Yet, it doesn't allow alpha-channel, so you wouldn't be able to specify transparent background of the ad, but it may solve your problem.

Comment: FYI: I'm using GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.0.jar, and my ads are generally graphical rather than text.

Comment: Just swapped the jar file for 6.0.1 in my libs directory, then did a "clean" then compiled and ran again... no change. The bug is still there :-(

Answer (score 0):

try to make the layout that you want to be transparent in XML, not dynamically. I had such problems on dynamically added ListView with transparent Items.

You have a game here, so of course what I suggested might not work, or will be hard to do, but you can Use a FrameLayout to put your layout on which you draw, and the transparent one on top of it. Also note, in such case the touches will go to the ad layout. It can be prevented, but is a bit like of a hack (I did it by the way once).

I don't know if this will work, but give a try.

Answer (score 0):

some ideas:

can you simply remove the line of setting the background to the lineraLayout :

```
transparent_linearlayout_to_hold_banner.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

?

also , instead of removing and adding the adView , can you instead toggle the visibility of the linearLayout (or the adView ) ?